# Shift Installation of PostgreSQL 15 from one hard drive to another in window server

Tags: postgresql, performance, windows-server

I have a PostgreSQL database installed on one of my four hard drives in a Windows Server 2012 R2 machine. I would like to move the database, along with all of its configurations, to another drive because my current hard disk is being heavily utilized by PostgreSQL, consuming a significant percentage of CPU power. What are the steps involved in doing this?

And what steps will be taken to lower this heavily used Postgres database's CPU costs?

Comment: I have already run backups of the database

Answer (score 1):

- stop the PostgreSQL server
- move the data directory to the other disk
- change the configuration of the PostgreSQL service to look for the data directory in the new location
- start the PostgreSQL server

Naturally, you should perform a backup before doing something like that.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to move the database ... because my current hard disk is being heavily utilized by PostgreSQL ...

What do you mean by "*utilized*"?
If you mean it's taking up a lot of space then, frankly, that's exactly what databases are *built* to do.  Capacity Planning (working out how much space you're going to need over time) is just another skill that the humble DBA has to gain.

However, ...
If it's continually *growing*, you might be missing some house-keeping Jobs or Tasks, like [AUTO]VACUUM.
If it's continually *writing* to disk, which will slow *everything* down, then you need to investigate the **queries** that are running and see what *they're* up to.
Common culprits for this sort of behaviour are large sort operations (ORDER BY clauses), which might be improvable by better indexing.  YMMV.

> ... consuming a significant percentage of CPU power.

That suggests a lot of work is being done *in memory*.
Again, examine the **queries**, Looking for WHERE clauses or JOINs on fields that aren't indexed.

Comment: Thanks for the respond maybe since my queries are coming from laravel project might be existing commands to check queries that took a long time and consumptions of CPU

Comment: Read up on PostgreSql's logging options: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html

Comment: this is well received i shall pass and read